# Keyboard Lag on startup in windows 8/8.1/10

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, keyboard, lag

Ever since Windows 8 I've noticed an issue where there is a severe typing lag immediately after boot.

Typing into any field will suffer a lag of anywhere up to 2 seconds per keystroke. This typically only lasts for about 15-20 seconds, then goes away. It only ever occcurs on boot

I've seen this across Windows 8/8.1/10, across two machines with differernt hardware and using the surface type cover and external keyboards. There's no common factor I can see.

Anyone else seen this? Know of a fix?

Comment: Does your HDD report itself as being healthy?  Does it happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ramhound don't know about safemode, but the HDD is fine. And as I said this has happened across several machines / configs. Not a hardware issue

Comment: I might have an answer to your problem.  I would just need an answer to all my questions.

Comment: It doesn't happen every time so there's no way to be sure, but I will test on safe mode tonight